# PostgreSQL: Order by name after a multiple-level hierarchy sort

Tags: postgresql

I'm currently exporting queries from Oracle to PostgreSQL, and I am stuck on this one which is used to sort directories:

```
WITH RECURSIVE R AS (
   SELECT ARRAY[ID] AS H
         ,ID
         ,PARENTID
         ,NAME
         ,1 AS level
   FROM   REPERTORIES
   WHERE  ID= (SELECT Min(ID) FROM REPERTORIES)

   UNION ALL
   SELECT R.H || A.ID
         ,A.ID
         ,A.PARENTID
         ,A.NAME
         ,R.level + 1
   FROM   REPERTORIES A
   JOIN   R ON A.PARENTID = R.ID
   )
SELECT NAME
      ,ID
      ,PARENTID
      , level
FROM  R
   ORDER BY H
```

It's partially working, each subdirectory is placed after his parent directory or a directory sharing the same parent directory (A directory can have subdirectories which also have subdirectories and so on)

But I need to also sort the directories that are at the same level by their NAME (while, of course, still having their subdirectories right next to them)

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance (and sorry if my English is hard to understand)

EDIT: Here is the orignial Oracle query:

```
SELECT NAME, ID, PARENTID, level
FROM REPERTORIES
CONNECT BY PRIOR ID = PARENTID
START WITH ID = (SELECT Min(ID) FROM REPERTORIES)
ORDER SIBLINGS BY NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the way you construct `h`, construct an array that contains the path names and order by that.

Comment: Thnks, I'm going to try this !

Answer (score -1):

The "order by H" is throwing me for a loop, however..
In general you need to do your sorting in the recursive part of the query to keep them "grouped" properly.

```
WITH RECURSIVE R AS (
   SELECT ARRAY[ID] AS H
         ,ID
         ,PARENTID
         ,NAME
         ,1 AS level
   FROM   REPERTORIES
   WHERE  ID= (SELECT Min(ID) FROM REPERTORIES)

   UNION ALL
   SELECT R.H || A.ID
         ,A.ID
         ,A.PARENTID
         ,A.NAME
         ,R.level + 1
   FROM   REPERTORIES A
   JOIN   R ON A.PARENTID = R.ID
   order by name
   )
SELECT NAME
      ,ID
      ,PARENTID
      , level
FROM  R
```

Comment: It says me that "ORDER BY in a recursive query isn't implanted", i've tried to do this :/